# Sorting of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Confusing !!!

I have one `NSMutableDictionary` called `tempDict`, having *keys* **Freight, Fuel , Discount** (and many more) with relevant *values*.

I am generating two different `NSMutableArrays` called `arrTVBuyCharge` and `arrTVBuyCost` from `tempDict` using this Code :

```
[arrTVBuyCharge addObjectsFromArray:[(NSArray *)[tempDict allKeys]]];
[arrTVBuyCost addObjectsFromArray:[(NSArray *)[tempDict allValues]]];
```

**Problem :** I want **Freight, Fuel and Discount** at the Top in the above arrays in same order (Ofcourse , with Ordering of *Values*).

**What is the Optimum way to achieve this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Get three objects separately :**

```
NSArray *mainKeys = @[@"Freight", @"Fuel", @"Discount"];
NSArray *mainValues = @[[tempDict valueForKey:@"Freight"],
        [tempDict valueForKey:@"Fuel"],
        [tempDict valueForKey:@"Discount"]
        ];
[arrTVBuyCharge addObjectsFromArray:mainKeys];
[arrTVBuyCost addObjectsFromArray:mainValues];
```

**2) Remove them from tempDict :**

```
[tempDict removeObjectsForKeys:mainKeys];
```

**3) Add the objects from Updated tempDict :**

```
[arrTVBuyCharge addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)[tempDict allKeys]];
[arrTVBuyCost addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)[tempDict allValues]];
```

This will make **Freight, Fuel and Discount** to be at index **0, 1 and 2** in your new Arrays.

Comment: I'll go with your Answer as it is Best Suited to situation in My Code. I Edited your answer to eliminate Crashes.

Answer (score 3):

It seems tricky at first, but it's simple when you think about it. All you want to do is get a sorted list of keys, and look up the value for each key as you add them to your arrays.

To get an array with the list of sorted keys:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[tempDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Then iterate through those and add them to NSMutableArrays:

```
NSMutableArray *arrTVBuyCharge = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrTVBuyCost = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
   [arrTVBuyCharge addObject:key];
   [arrTVBuyCost addObject:[tempDict objectForKey:key]];
}
```

For even better performance, use the `initWithCapacity` method for the NSMutableArrays since you know the size.

This is the standard way of doing it.

Comment: _+1_ This is definitely the way to do it. In case you need sorted values, use `-keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:`.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I just want to know How your solution is better than satheeshwaran's Answer. There are no loops involved in his Answer.

Comment: @iMartin, is the order you add the values going to be the same order you want them sorted, which you will need for satheshwaran's solution to work? If so, then just use an array, not a dictionary. I did not invent this solution. You will find it in almost every tutorial on NSDictionary. It's the standard way. It's simple. You don't necessary need the for loop, depends on what you're doing with the data.

Answer (score 1):

Man, NSMutableDictionary always returns keys in a disordered fashion, if you really want to maintain order then you can sort it in alphabetical order or you can add 01, 02 ,03 serial numbers before your values to sort them in the order they were put it, later trim the first two characters of the string and use it.

Comment: C'mon , I know that "NSMutableDictionary always returns keys in a disordered fashion". That's why I am asking the Question. I know I can't sort the NSMutableDictionary. So what's the best way to solve it ?

Comment: Yea I told you can add serial numbers or something while you populate the array and then sort them back using [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                                     @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]. I had a similar problem so I did the same. I added 01.the value, 02.the value into my arrays and then sorted it. When I wanted to use the array contents i took subsStringFromIndex:3

Comment: I am considering your solution.